# Confusion in Reactjs keys

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a Reactjs app and in which i'm rendering something like that in one of the component. I'm little confused where should i put the unique key. I'm constantly getting warning about it , don't know why because it seems like to me i have placed the keys in correct place.

```
<Accordion allowZeroExpanded={true}>
  {sideDrawerList.map(item => (
    <AccordionItem key={item.key}>
      <AccordionItemHeading>
        <AccordionItemButton>
          <div>
            <p>{item.title}</p>
            <img src="some_url" alt="logo" />
          </div>
        </AccordionItemButton>
      </AccordionItemHeading>
      <AccordionItemPanel>
        <div>
          {item.childs.map(navItem => (
            <p key={navItem.linkPath}>
              <Link to={navItem.linkPath}>{navItem.linkText}</Link>
            </p>
          ))}
        </div>
      </AccordionItemPanel>
    </AccordionItem>
  ))}
</Accordion>
```

Comment: What warning are you getting? The keys have to be unique for every element in an array, so that might be your issue.

Comment: `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` This is the warning i'm getting and i'm making sure all the keys are unique.

Comment: check your key values. Maybe they are the same

Comment: I have checked,  they all are different.

Comment: I would delete components one by one until the error disappears. so you can find a problem place

Answer (score 0):

Your placement of key is perfect, as official React docs suggest, key must be added to the first element inside the map.

Your problem seems to be that the keys you are using namely: `item.key` or `navItem.linkPath` seem to have duplicate values. This is the reason for the warning you are getting as inside a list, all keys should be unique. In cae you dont have anything unique in your dataset then you may consider adding index from map as the key but index is not recommended usually. Sample:

```
list.map((currElement, index) => {
    <element key={index} />
});
```

Here is why using index as key is discouraged, straing from react docs:

> When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the
>   item index as a key as a last resort:
>
> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may
>   change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues
>   with component state. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an
>   in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a
>   key. If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then
>   React will default to using indexes as keys.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And yeah i'm familiar with issue if we use index as a key.